# Get output of a java application C#

Tags: java, c#

This may be hard to understand, **but I want to get the output of a java application in a console C# app.**

When you start a java application with Process.Start in a C# console app, the java application takes control, and all lines are written using System.Out.Println().

I want to start a java application, make it so System.out.println() gets stored in a variable and not printed, and then reprint what the variable is with Console.WriteLine()

*Allow me to rephrase.* #1 Start java app in c# console app with process.start. #2 Cancel java's attempts to output what it was going to output with System.out.prinln(), and instead store it in a variable/string. #3 reprint that string using Console.WriteLine().

Redirecting standard output does not work for this.

If you are wondering, this is for minecraft bukkit.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput%28v=vs.110%29.aspx has example

Comment: What lashane said... or do something along the lines of Named Pipes, TCP/IP, Filesystem, Mailslots, etc.

Comment: @Lashane Redirect standard output does not produce results I am expecting. It doesn't work.

Comment: I feel like using filesystem is messy...  I want a more programmatic way of going about this

Comment: @halpme142 it should not produce results you're expecting, it should return what was printed to standard output, also there is exists `RedirectStandardError`

Comment: I still need help with this... Anyone??

Answer (score 4):

Java application:

```
public class JavaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Java application outputs something into stdout");
        System.err.println("Java application outputs something into stderr");
    }
}
```

C# application

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace CaptureProcessStdOutErr
{
  public class Program
  {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("java", "JavaApplication") // proper path to java, main java class, classpath, jvm parameters, etc must be specified or use java -jar jarName.jar if packaged into a single jar
      {
        RedirectStandardError  = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        UseShellExecute        = false
      };

      var process = Process.Start(startInfo);

      process.WaitForExit();

      Console.WriteLine("Captured stderr from java process:");
      Console.WriteLine(process.StandardError.ReadToEnd());
      Console.WriteLine();
      Console.WriteLine("Captured stdout from java process");
      Console.WriteLine(process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
    }
  }
}
```

This assumes java.exe is in the PATH.

Compile JavaApplication and put JavaApplication.class file next to C# application (CaptureProcessStdOutErr.exe)

run CaptureProcessStdOutErr.exe

Output:

```
Captured stderr from java process:
Java application outputs something into stderr

Captured stdout from java process
Java application outputs something into stdout
```